# What is the quickest way to add pairs of edge loops?

Tags: modeling, edges

I need to create many pairs of edge loops on different objects. The way I do this is shown in the animation below.

There is a further step I often do which is moving the edge loop using its transform value in the properties panel, to ensure they are always same distance apart.

Is there an easier way to add the same number of edge loops again to the side of the original 3 loops?

[image: example]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Select all the loops that you want to add loops around with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Click</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to start beveling
3. Scroll up on the mouse wheel to increase the segments to 2

[image: bevel loop cuts]

Answer (score 5):

You could add two times as many loop cuts as you need, and just sale the pairs together. This way it is easier to make sure all are aligned and the same size.

The easiest way to do it is just add the loop cuts, then with them still selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>. That will *bevel* the edges, but on a flat surface it will just subdivide the loop cuts.